# How to merge data table in R by specified data column?

Tags: r, csv, merge

I have two csv files. Shown in pictures.

Files are shown in the following link.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bDr9-gywQuVCcfp18JIwoybecTY-VYvP?usp=sharing

Following code are the current code I did.
Now I have to merge table by PdId column.

I need to have the overview of the San Francisco crime data.

Thanks

`library(data.table)`

`fread("~/datasets/crime_location.csv")`

`fread("~/datasets/crime_detail.csv")`

`df1 <-("~/datasets/crime_location.csv")`

`df2 <-("~/datasets/crime_detail.csv")`

Comment: Try `df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = 'PdId')`.

Comment: I have try it. These are the error message : **Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column**

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Images are not helpful. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thanks. I put the link on the web. You could click the link and download it.

Comment: Are both the columns called `PdId` ? Did you read the data into R? `df1 <- fread("~/datasets/crime_location.csv")` and same for `df2` ?

Comment: Yes, I did it the same for f2. RStudio could read both data frame.

Answer (score 0):

You fread something into a variable. This is probably it.

```
library(data.table)
loc=fread("~/datasets/crime_location.csv")
det=fread("~/datasets/crime_detail.csv")
df3=merge(loc, det, by = 'PdId')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- as.data.frame(df1)
df2 <- as.data.frame(df2)

df1$PdId <- as.character(df1$PdId)
df2$PdId <- as.character(df2$PdId)
df3 <- full_join(df1, df2, by = "PdId")
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It shows $ operator is invalid for atomic vector.

Comment: you change your data to the data frame. ```df1 <- as.data.frame(df1), df2 <- as.data.frame(df2)```